# ionic 1 check internet when app is working

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I try to check if internet is working when I run the app. It works well on my computer but after compiling apk and running the app on my smartphone, this code doesn't work properly; could you help me ?

```js
.run(function($window, $rootScope) {
 console.log($cordovaNetwork.getNetwork());
 $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
 $window.addEventListener("offline", function() {
  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
   $rootScope.online = false;
  });
 }, false);
 $window.addEventListener("online", function() {
  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
   $rootScope.online = true;
  });
 }, false);
})
```

regards

Answer (score 1):

Its not good practice to use `navigator.onLine` on Android devices. Each device uses different version of Chromium and on some devices it will not work as expected.

I suggest you to use [org.apache.cordova.network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) plugin that calls **native** API for network information (advantage)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use cordova network Plugin([Cordova Network Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)). Use can use the code below

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    // Check for network connection
    if(window.Connection) {
      if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        $ionicPopup.confirm({
          title: 'No Internet Connection',
          content: 'Sorry, no Internet connectivity detected. Please reconnect and try again.'
        })
        .then(function(result) {
          if(!result) {
            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
          }
        });
      }
    }

  });
})
```

Comment: when i build the apk it doesn't work properly. Nothing appears.

Comment: check whether cordova has been included and check whether the cordova plugin has been installed properly . i have used this code its working for me.can you fiddle your code ??